# requestlayout doing nothing in 4.4.3

Tags: android, android-layout

We have an app that's rather complex with a fairly deep view hierarchy. It works fine on every device between 4.x and 4.4.2, however in 4.4.3 weird stuff starts happening. Sometimes (read most of the time) when we show a page with a horizontal scrollview and a viewpager we can't scroll the horizontal scrollview and the viewpager doesn't measure new views. I've chased the bug down and the horizontal scrollview seems to scroll fine, but the call we do to requestLayout sees that isLayoutRequested on getParent is already true, and stops doing anything (and therefor doesn't redraw).

When this happens I've set a breakpoint on the base "View" class onLayout function. The debugger does stop there when I draw up the initial layout, but when I end up in a state where it's broken triggering requestLayout never triggers a onLayout in ANY view.

In what scenarios can you call requestLayout on a view and never have a debugger trigger on View.OnLayout? How can I debug this without having the 4.4.3 sources so I can see whats going on deeper in the stack?

Comment: It'd be REALLY helpfull to have the source code for ViewRootImpl.java between 4.4.2 and 4.4.3... but I guess that'll take a while to become available :/

Comment: I thought Android 4.4.3 source is already available, is this particular class missing from there?

Comment: [Source code for ViewRootImpl.java in 4.4.3 (KitKat MR2)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-mr2-release/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java), and [the same file in 4.4.2 (KitKat MR1)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/kitkat-mr1-release/core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java). 

AFAIK Github doesn't let you compare individual files between tags, so you need to clone the repo and do something like `git diff kitkat-mr1-release kitkat-mr2-release -- core/java/android/view/ViewRootImpl.java` to view the diff

Comment: I'm used to code drops taking time, I just assumed it wasn't dropped yet, I'll dig into this now.